# picasa link to usable cooliris link

Tags: php, str-replace, cooliris

Ok, I've got this link:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/110727246651632161982/2042011#
```

and I want to use it for cooliris, on their website they make it like this:

```
picasaweb.google.com%2F%3Fuser%3D110727246651632161982%26album%3D2042011
```

I want users to post the normal picasa link into my website, then the link has to be replaced and pasted into my database. I know how to do that, but how to get from the picasa link to the usable cooliris link?

Answer (score 0):

**Example: DECODE**

```
$url = 'picasaweb.google.com%2F%3Fuser%3D110727246651632161982%26album%3D2042011';
echo urldecode($url);
```

**Output**

> picasaweb.google.com/?user=110727246651632161982&album=2042011

**Example: ENCODE**

```
$url = 'picasaweb.google.com/110727246651632161982/2042011#';
echo urlencode($url);
```

**Output**

> picasaweb.google.com%2F110727246651632161982%2F2042011%23

**References:**

- [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)
- [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Decode does the job - till the album selection, so it only shows my 4 albums. Encode won't work at all...